# Minor bug in pararrayfun? Is there a workaround (threads vs processes)?

Tags: octave

I am using Octave version `4.2.2`, but I think the question applies to previous versions as well.

I want to know if the following behavior is well-known and caused by my ignorance or if it is a bug that should be addressed, and also if there is a workaround. Note that I am focusing on parallelization in situations where vectorization is not possible, and where copy by values are not an option.

Basically, my problem is that functions such as `pararrayfun` or `parcellfun` seem to violate the principle that ***the properties of handles are passed by reference***.

As an example, suppose we define

```
classdef data_class < handle
   properties
      data
   end
end
```

and that we want to take each element from the `.data` property of one object `input_arr` from this class, apply some stochastic function `fancy_func` to them, and copy the result to the corresponding index of the `.data` property of another object `arr` of this class. The `.data` property is just a matrix of size `12*1`, and we want to have `4` processes that each process `3` elements.

```
elem_per_process=3;
num_processes=4;
start_indexes={1,4,7,10};
function []=fill_arr(start_idx,num_elems,in_arr_handle,arr_to_fill_handle)
    for i=1:num_elems
        arr_to_fill_handle.data(start_idx+i-1,:)=fancy_func(in_arr_handle.data(start_idx+i-1,:));
    end 
end

filler=@(start_idx)fill_arr(start_idx,elem_per_process,input_arr,arr);

cellfun(filler,start_indexes);%works fine

parcellfun(num_processes,filler,start_indexes);% PROBLEM! Nothing is copied
```

So, this is actually worse that what I thought:

- `parcellfun` copies object handle properties by value
- It breaks code that works with `cellfun` !

A quick look at

```
<octave_dir>/packages/parallel-3.1.1/parcellfun.m
```

seems to indicate that the parallelization relies on processes instead of threads (also note `pararrayfun` uses `parcellfun` at its core), so this is expected. What bothers me is that it does so without a single warning, while going against the fundamental properties that many Octave users expect to hold.

So,  to summarize:

- Is this as a (minor) bug?
- Is there any way to parallelize using threads instead of processes (for situations where vectorization is not possible, and where copy by value is unacceptable)?

Comment: the functions `parcellfun` and `pararrayfun` were written way before Octave had classdef.  Consider filling a bug report.

Comment: As a workaround you can use `mat2cell` to split `data` into a cell array and apply `parcellfun` to it and concatenate the result into a matrix.

Comment: @rahnema1 Thanks, but I just checked, and it seems that `mat2cell` makes a copy of its argument, and also, it doesn't alleviate the problem that once I feed the cell to `parcellfun`, it is going to make a copy of said cell, and I will still lose the ability to do the operations in place.

Comment: You can time it .If splitting and merging the array is is more time consuming than `fancy_func` I think you may not get much benefits from parallelization.

Comment: GNU Octave is single threaded and the function of parcellfun is documented in it's help: (I cite only some parts here): "..using multiple processes...this function is implemented using "fork" and a number of pipes for IPC". Olaf held a great talk at CERN, have a look: https://indico.cern.ch/event/609833/contributions/2519218/
So to answer your question: No, this isn't a bug, it's per current design. Feel free to help to improve this situation (please send patches to the patchtracker) and/or ask on the maintainers list for help